# How to embed ruby into javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

using hardcoded assets: `icon: 'assets/pin-red-48.png'` doesn't show up on my VPS (but does on localhost) so I need to swap this out with `<%= image_tag %>`?

First I tried changing file extension to .js.erb and embedding ruby, but that didn't work so...

I tried passing the embedded ruby through the .html.erb file:

`<script>var userDesIcon = "<%= image_tag('pin-red-48.png') %>";</script>`

and then in the .js file call it right at the top:

`(function($) {
     var userDesIcon;
  $(document).ready(function () {`

then later in the function call it: `icon: userDesIcon,`

Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using the asset pipeline, change the file name back to `.js.erb` and then use this:

```
var userDesIcon = "<%= image_path('pin-red-48.png') %>";
// rest of your JS code here
```